Selecting certain cells with text and hiding the columns
I recorded a macro where I want any cell containing the text "Hide" to be selected then hidden.
I used this YouTube video as a guide. Simple macro to hide columns based on cell value
Sub Hide_Columns()
'
' Hide_Columns Macro
'

'
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 2).Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
End Sub

I get

Run-time error '1004'; No cells were found


These macros work in my sample file.
Sub hide()

Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To 100
If Cells(1, i).Value = "Hide" Then
Columns(i).Hidden = True
Else
End If

Next i

End Sub


Sub unhide()

Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To 100
Columns(i).Hidden = False
Next i

End Sub


You can simply use Conditional Formatting and bypass the need for VBA altogether. In the example below I have used your value of 'Hide' to hide the cell but you can use any other value:

Select your range
Click on Conditional Formatting
Select 'Format only cells that contain'
In the rule description: Cell Value equal to Hide
Click the Format button
Select the Number Tab
Select the 'Custom' category
In the Type: field enter 3 semicolons (;;;)
Click Ok


Thank you for posting.  I actually needed the column hidden.  Your instructions hide the text but the column remained.
